# Find the median lifetime

Tags: statistics

a certain type of light bulb has lifetimes that follows an exponential distribution with mean 1000 hours. Find the median lifetime. (ie the lifetime x such that 50% of the light bulbs fail before x.)
The answer is 1000log2.I do not know to to get the answer.please help.
Thank you!

Comment: Hint:  What does your book say is the _cumulative probability distribution function_ or CDF of this random variable? For what value of $x$ does $F(x)$ equal $\frac{1}{2}$?  If your book does not mention the CDF of exponential random variables at all, does it at least tell you that $P\{X > t\} = e^{-\lambda t}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let random variable $X$ be the lifetime of the bulb.

The density function of $X$ is $\frac{1}{1000}e^{-x/1000}$ (for $x\ge 0$).
We want to find $m$ so that
$$\Pr(X\gt m)=\frac{1}{2}.$$
So we want
$$\int_m^\infty \frac{1}{1000}e^{-x/1000}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Integrate. We get
$$e^{-m/1000}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Take the natural logarithm of both sides. We get
$$-\frac{m}{1000}=\ln(1/2)=-\ln 2.$$
It follows that $m=1000\ln 2$.

**Remark:** The exponential distribution fits the lifetime of real-life incandescent bulbs quite poorly.

Comment: You are welcome. I left some details (the integration) to you.